# Bad configuration of hibernate for spring application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-session

I have a problems with hibernate in my Spring application. I think that there must be bad configuration.

*hibernate.cfg.xml*

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cloud_app?autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    ...
```

*persistanceContext.xml*

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cloud_app" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="20" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="120" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1200" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

When I use in my application `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, it still throws the exception

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

But when I use `sessionFactory.openSession()`, it solves problems, but makes another issues. So my question is, how can I reach a state - one session for whole application. How reach that when I call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, session will be exist.
I am confused, I read a lot of threads how to solve it, but without no success.

**UPDATE**
When I get some object and then I try to change it

```
Opportunity opportunity = opportunityDao.get(idOpportunity);
opportunity.setOrder(order);
opportunityDao.edit(opportunity);
```

code from `get` method

```
public T get(Integer id) {
    T object = (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    return object;
}
```

code from `edit` method

```
public void edit(T object) {
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(object);
}
```

It throws me `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things

1. Your `hibernate.connection.*` properties are useless as you are injecting a `DataSource` inside your spring application
2. The other properties for dialect and show_sql are already set in the spring configuration, so in short (due to 1 and 2) you can delete the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.
3. Use the the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` convenience class.

Leaving you with this

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimize">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="your.package.with.entities.here" />
</bean>
```

That at least cleans up your configuration (and moving everything into a single file).

The problem you have is due to improper transaction configuration. You have the how, the `HibernateTransactionManager` but not the when/where configured. I would expect a `<tx:annotation-driven />` or `<tx:advice />` with `<aop:config />` to enable transactions.

I suggest a read of the [transaction chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) in the Spring Reference Guide, for more information on hibernate read [the hibernate section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate).

Comment: Thank you, it partially solved problems. I can make operations over entities using `getCurrentSession()`. But there is another problem, I think that it relates with multiple opened sessions. Look on the update please.

Comment: That has to do with wrong transaction setup. Your service layer should be the transactional layer not the dao. So basically the method that does get/modify/update should be transactional.

Comment: It is weird, because there is set <tx:annotation-driven /> on webapp context and every service that call dao methods have @Service annotation.

Comment: Your advice was correct. I had transactions enabled, but there didn't work OSIV filter. I had to set it like interceptor - it fixed all issues.

Comment: `@Service` has nothing to do with `@Transactional`. Instead of using the OSIVF or OSIVI simply annotate your service with `@Transactional`  (as I mentioned in my previous comment).